# HTML Pictures Horizontial Row

Tags: html, css, scroll

I was wondering if there was a way to make a div containing images have an overflow that scrolls horizontially, as depicted in the projected diagram below:

[alt text http://www.zip-cover.com/development/image_carosoul/slideshow.jpg](http://www.zip-cover.com/development/image_carosoul/slideshow.jpg)

as always, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the width and amount of images inside the div to prevent it from wrapping:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner" style="width: 3200px;">
        <img src="1.jpg" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <img src="3.jpg" />
        <img src="4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

#inner {
    height: 600px;
}
```

This example assumes your images are 800x600px, adjust as necessary.

Comment: Is there any way that the width of the inner div can be automatic?

Comment: No, but you can use Javascript to calculate it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
#imageContainer { 
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

Make sure the images aren't higher than the height parameter.

Comment: What does your code look like?
`<div id="#imageContainer"><img src="x.jpg"><img src="y.jpg"><img src="z.jpg"></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
overflow-x: auto;
```